# Query sqlite every 10s vs using timeout vs node-cron

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, settimeout

I have an sqlite flavor DB which contains one table, its has about 10k items with 5 columns. In one of the columns I have a 'timer' basically a number I have given and the purpose of it is to decrease it as time (ideally every second) goes by till it reaches zero. When it reaches zero I want to perform an action.

*Thought process*

**1st:** I can update my db for every item needed (probably for the 2k out of the 10k) every 10s (setInternal) -as to not stress it- and check whether any items reached zero. I am reluctant about this way as I feel it might not be so efficient.

**2nd:** Since I am on nodejs I can use timeouts. Read once my DB get all the wanted users, and for every one of them create a setTimeout method. After a minute or so update the DB, nested-setInternal Since each of the setTimeout take about 35bytes of the nodejs heap its not a bad method. -Right now I think this is the wat to go.

**3rd:** I found out this https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron github, which basically is a task scheduler. After looking at its code for a bit I dont think its bad but I really dont think I have to use an external package here.

Note: Whatever of the above methods where I to use in case the process crashed they would be resetted (loses completely the point) without updating my DB periodically so I guess I cant avoid that.

**Question:** What should I do to efficiently update a timer in my DB every few seconds-(so all the time my process is alive)- without draining my resources?

Sorry to those that read the whole thing and feel they lost their time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store the remaining time in the database. Instead store the absolute timestamp of the action.

Then you can simply ask for any actions that need to be handled:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM actions
WHERE timestamp > (last handled timestamp)
  AND timestamp <= (current timestamp);
```

(If the `timestamp` column is indexed, this query is very efficient.)

You can also get the time until the next event, to program a timeout:

```sql
SELECT timestamp
FROM actions
WHERE timestamp > (last handled timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response I was asleep, thank you that seems like a pretty good way.

Answer (score 0):

Flow can be as follow

1. On Starting server one method is called which will check the timer field in table if found zero for any record it will just perform your operation. (use promise in operation).
2. When promise get over call another function and in that function wait for some second then again call previous function.

You can use recursive function calling with some time delay. This delay is just for reducing database load or deadlocks.

Comment: So you suggest something like: call_DB->update timer in DB->if zero - action else setTimeout (1s) ->call again. Basically the first method I said right?

Comment: I just create one function say "checkTimer"                                                                        if timer found zero the from this function call "updateDbFunction" else settimeout(10s)->call again "checkTimer". IN updateDbFunction process your operation THEN settimeout(10s)->call again "checkTimer"